# how to do this.. backwards?

Tags: php, loops

I currently have:

```
$i = 1;
while {
  echo $i;
  $i++;
}
```

And it shows:

```
1
2
3
4 etc..
```

How would I make it display backwards?

For example

```
4
3
2
1 etc..
```

I basically want to do the exact same thing but flip it around.

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid PHP -- you're missing a condition for the `while`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$i = 10;
while($i>0) {
  echo $i;
  $i--;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Example - Print number through 0 to 5 with PHP For Loop

```
for($i=0; $i<=5; $i=$i+1)
{
    echo $i." ";
}
```

In the above example, we set a counter variable $i to 0. In the second statement of our for loop, we set the condition value to our counter variable $i to 5, i.e. the loop will execute until $i reaches 5. In the third statement, we set $i to increment by 1.

The above code will output numbers through 0 to 5 as 0 1 2 3 4 5.
Note: The third increment statement can be set to increment by any number. In our above example, we can set $i to increment by 2, i.e., $i=$i+2. In this case the code will produce 0 2 4.

Example - Print number through 5 to 0 with PHP For Loop

What if we want to go backwards, that is, print number though 0 to 5 in reverse order? We simple initialize the counter variable $i to 5, set its condition to 0 and decrement $i by 1.

```
for($i=5; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
{
    echo $i." ";
}
```

The above code will output number from 5 to 0 as 5 4 3 2 1 0 looping backwards.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to back-word sr number as per your count of rows in result then use this.

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$x = $num_rows;

$x--;
```

Comment: The question didn't mention MySQL… and that isn't a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 4;
while($i > 0) {
  echo $i--;
}
```

Comment: Yep, i've got it working - thank you! I basically did $i = mysql num rows, then used $i--